# Удалённое подключение к пользователям в домене Windows Server по Active Directory

Tags: windows, сервер, windows-server, directory

Извините за глупый вопрос, но помогите пожалуйста юному эникейщику.
Есть домен-контроллер с развёрнутым в нём Active Directory, есть пользователи.
Как к ним можно подключаться удалённо? Стандартным "Подключение к удалённому рабочему столу", если я подключаюсь - я просто заменяю текущую сессию пользователя.
Так с помощью каких средств я могу к ним подключаться? (не по AnyDesk конечно хотелось бы).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Mstsc.exe [/shadow:sessionID [/v:Servername] [/control] [/noConsentPrompt] [/prompt]]
```

Параметр shadow позволяет не заменять сессию. Номера сессий можно получить через [qwinsta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/qwinsta)

Comment: Привет, спасибо за твой ответ. Я подключился удалённо на домен-контроллер. И при вводе команды qwinsta, я не получаю сессии пользователей. Получаю только сеансы services (id 0), rdp-tcp#5 (id 1), console (id 3), rdp-tcp (id 65536). Может мне нужно что-то развернуть ещё на домен-контроллере?

Comment: Их надо получать с машины, к которой подключаешься. То есть укажи сервер.

Comment: Спасибо! Я разобрался